# In function, jQuery selector returns PreviousObject instead of selected object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to stick a second menu on my site to the top menu and I have several menus in two bootstrap columns (col-8 and col-4). So, while I used jQuery selectors out of the function, it worked well. But when I decided to refactor my code and create a function which gets class as a parameter, it actually stopped working correctly.
Element $element is just a div element with class ".navbar.navbar-default.stick-left".

Here the code:

```
var stickelement = function(classid) {
    $element = $(classid);
    console.log($element);
    if ($element.length) {

        elementOffset = $element.offset().top;

        $(window).scroll(function (e) {
            scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + $('.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top').height();
            distance = elementOffset - scrollTop;

            if (distance < 0 && $element.css('position') != 'fixed') {
                $element.css({
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'margin': '0px',
                    'top': ($('.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top').height()).toString() + 'px'
                });
            }
            if (distance > 0 && $element.css('position') == 'fixed') {
                $element.css({'position': 'static', 'margin': '50px'});
            }
        });
    }
};

stickelement(".navbar.navbar-default.stick-left");
```

After reloading page I see in my console only n.fn.init[0] with unitialized "top" field inside of the **proto** object and length 0.

Where did I make mistake?

Comment: What is the element $el?

Comment: Element $el is the wrong variable after previous editing and this source code stucked in my buffer instead of the right one. I changed the code above.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved my problem, but the second one has appeared. I'm trying to use two calls to the $(window).scroll asynchronously:

```
var stickelement = function(classid) {
    $element = $(classid);
    console.log($element);
    if ($element.length) {
        elementOffset = $element.offset().top;

        $(window).scroll(function (e) {
            scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() + $('.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top').height();
            distance = elementOffset - scrollTop;

            if (distance < 0 && $element.css('position') != 'fixed') {
                $element.css({
                    'position': 'fixed',
                    'margin': '0px',
                    'top': ($('.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top').height()).toString() + 'px'
                });
            }
            if (distance > 0 && $element.css('position') == 'fixed') {
                $element.css({'position': 'static', 'margin': '50px'});
            }
        });
    }
};

stickelement('.stick-left');
stickelement('.stick-right');
```

But they don't work simultaneously. Only one of two menus can stick to the top this way.
How to correct my solution in order to stick two menus to the top menu?